# is there a way to control the types of windows that a specific app is allowed to open?

Tags: mac

or by default, always push an app's windows to back?
i have an app that is very useful and normally confined to the status bar but has a popup window appearing every hour or so which can't be prevented so i am trying to block it completely.

i could write an applescript that listens 24/7 for the window to appear but surely there is a more permanent control that can be implemented.

the pushing to back by default would be excellent.

Comment: in this case, nord, but i want to be able to apply this to any app.

Comment: One of the _tools_ I use is [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org), and in particular its [**hs.application.watcher API**](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.watcher.html) using its `activated/deactivated` _constants_. However, depending on the _application_ and the _type_ of _window_ it may not detect it. As an example, the question you asked yesterday about `screencaptureui`, it does not detect this because the type of _window_ and the _properties_ it exposes. Anyway, **Hammerspoon** has lots of good uses and you might want to check it out. (Not affiliated, just a user.)